# Unable to access an Image from a .jsp file in Tomcat

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, jsp, tomcat, vscode-extensions

I am working with **VSCODE**.

I have a **Java Web Application** in the following path:
C:\CODIGO\IDEA_PROJECTS\TESTS\SFES\SFEAAPP\sfeaapp

Using **Maven** I package the web 'sfeaapp' app to this **.war** file:
C:\CODIGO\IDEA_PROJECTS\TESTS\SFES\SFEAAPP\sfeaapp\target\sfeaapp.war

Using **Community Server Connector**, I deploy that .war file to this **Tomcat** path:
C:\Users\jl.lmnchr.rsp\redhat-community-server-connector\runtimes\installations\tomcat-9.0.41\apache-tomcat-9.0.41\webapps\sfeaapp.war

I have this source **.jsp**:
C:\CODIGO\IDEA_PROJECTS\TESTS\SFES\SFEAAPP\sfeaapp\src\main\webapp\index.jsp

With the next content:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="/images/common/logo.jpg">
    </body>
</html>
```

That image file is located in:
C:\CODIGO\IDEA_PROJECTS\TESTS\SFES\SFEAAPP\sfeaapp\src\main\webapp\images\common\logo.jpg
And also in:
C:\Users\jl.lmnchr.rsp\redhat-community-server-connector\runtimes\installations\tomcat-9.0.41\apache-tomcat-9.0.41\webapps\sfeaapp\images\common\logo.jpg

But when I hit **http://localhost:8080/sfeaapp/index.jsp**, that image is not loaded.

Is there a way to fix it **without changing the code** of the index.jsp, **nor changing the location of the image**?

Comment: I have to ask: Why the constraints "_without changing the code_" and "_nor changing the location of the image_"? Basically, the structure described in the question conflicts with [what Maven expects to work with](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html).  It also does not fit with how Maven expects to handle [external resources](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html). Sorry, I don't have a solution that fits into your constraints - and if such a solution exists, it may be quite unpleasant.

Comment: The origin of these two limitations comes from the fact that we are trying to migrate a project where this misuse is made extensively. The goal is to keep everything working with minimal changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You explicitly address the image starting from the root folder. So the only option that I can see that keeps your (artificial) constraint is to rename your war file to ROOT.war, which will cause tomcat to deploy it to / instead of /sfeaapp.

The proper fix would be to include the context path in the image's URL or address it through a relative URL, but that would drop your constraint

Comment: Best solution was to copy folders 'images', 'js', 'css' to 'ROOT' folder